# How to access Google Cloud SQL by Python in Google Compute Engine

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I am new to programming and Google service. I have read [this document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-compute-engine) and set up Cloud SQL access by IP address.

However for access from Python, [the documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-sql) is only for App Engine and using Proxy instead. How can I access from Python in Google Compute Engine? Thanks

Comment: Did you check [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-compute-engine) and [this](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app)?

Comment: @Mangu I have read [that document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app). So My python script on Compute Engine should use proxy to access SQL Cloud?

Comment: If your Cloud SQL instance is Second Gen, yes. There is an example in that very same page for both configuring the Proxy and connecting from your Compute instance to your Cloud SQL instance via the proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Credit @Mangu

Depending upon the application and the requirements, you can configure to connect to the Cloud SQL from python in [compute engine using external IP](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-compute-engine) of the Cloud SQL instances or use [Cloud SQL Proxy with python](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-external-app#languages) (The Cloud SQL Proxy is available only for Second Generation instances.)

Here is another complete example [tutorial of using Cloud SQL with Python Bookshelf application.](https://cloud.google.com/python/getting-started/using-cloud-sql)